# OpenGL Calculate z coordinate from x and y

Tags: java, opengl

Say i have drawn a quad with points A(0,0,a) B(1,0,b) C(1,1,c) and D(0,1,d) and want to find out the coordinates P(0.6,0.25,p), how would i go about doing this? I'm hoping theres something less processor heavy i've missed, because thus far i've been trying to take the difference of A.x and B.x and then C.x and D.x and then finding the difference between those and its all a bit messy.

For example, say i want to find the point where the mouse is in this picture :

[image]

Is there an easier or less processor heavy way of finding the point there?
(Not picking or raycasting, because the mouse wont be there, the mouse was just pointing at where i'd like it to happen, for example)

Answer (score 0):

FYI: Using ray-casting should be adequate to do what you are looking for.  You need to rotate the perspective of your fulcrum to focus from the absolute 0 above and absolute 1 of the location of your model.  If you want another way to check quickly, barycentric coordinates are also useful.

Using barycentric coordinates you can determine a point inside a triangle:

```
function pointInTriangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x, y:Number):Boolean
{
 var denominator:Number = ((y2 - y3)*(x1 - x3) + (x3 - x2)*(y1 - y3));
 var a:Number = ((y2 - y3)*(x - x3) + (x3 - x2)*(y - y3)) / denominator;
 var b:Number = ((y3 - y1)*(x - x3) + (x1 - x3)*(y - y3)) / denominator;
 var c:Number = 1 - a - b;

 return 0 <= a && a <= 1 && 0 <= b && b <= 1 && 0 <= c && c <= 1;
}
```

Barycentric coordinate allows to express new p coordinates as a linear combination of p1, p2, p3. More precisely, it defines 3 scalars a, b, c:

> x = a * x1 + b * x2  + c * x3 y = a * y1 + b * y2 + c * y3 a + b + c =
>   1

The way to compute a, b, c is as follows:

> a = ((y2 - y3)*(x - x3) + (x3 - x2)*(y - y3)) / ((y2 - y3)*(x1 - x3) +
>   (x3 - x2)*(y1 - y3)) b = ((y3 - y1)*(x - x3) + (x1 - x3)*(y - y3)) /
>   ((y2 - y3)*(x1 - x3) + (x3 - x2)*(y1 - y3)) c = 1 - a - b

p is inside of T if and only if 0 <= a <= 1 and 0 <= b <= 1 and 0 <= c <= 1

reference http://totologic.blogspot.fr/2014/01/accurate-point-in-triangle-test.html

Comment: My god that looks complex... Right, so i'm trying to work out the z value of the drawn quad thats underneath an entity that will move over it. If i still can ray cast, i'd like to because it strikes me as helpful

Comment: It has been years, but I will see if I can pull some old code that would help you.  I have done it in the past.  Raycasting is fast and accurate.

Comment: How would i ray cast from a point to a point in the world though? I cant think through it, and my current raycast method i use for spawning entities only works from the screen

Comment: What graphics library are you using?

Comment: LWJGL, but i can convert from anything given enough time, i've been trying to do this for about 6 hours and any help is help, frankly

Comment: That should be acceptable.  I am trying to get some old code to recompile, I will update my answer with some more useful code, using OpenGL, so it will be closely compatible.

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to be the prettiest read, but here are a couple of samples of what you are looking to do.  A downloadable project would probably be more useful for you, not sure that I could post all of that here though.

(This is basic ray-triangle intersection)

The use of OpenGL should be noted (this is c++ code below)
The key part of the code that you would want to replicate outside of OpenGL (if glaux.lib is not used):

```
gluUnProject( PosX, PosY, 0, modelview, projection, viewport, &x1, &x2, &x3);
vnear.x = (float)x1; vnear.y = (float)x2; vnear.z = (float)x3;
gluUnProject( PosX, PosY, 1.0, modelview, projection, viewport, &x1, &x2, &x3);
vfar.x = (float)x1; vfar.y = (float)x2; vfar.z = (float)x3;
```

A basic collision class should be created:

```
class CCollision
{
public:
        CVec vnear;     // Where is 0 and where is 100% of fulcrum
        CVec vfar;
public:
    CCollision(void);
    ~CCollision(void);
public:
    bool checkLine (CVec &v1, CVec &v2,CVec &v3, CVec &p );
    bool checkLine( float *triangle, CVec &p );
    bool checkLine( float* v1, float* v2, float* v3, CVec &p ); 
    void projectRay ( int x, int y );
};
```

The definitions are as follows:

```
CCollision::CCollision(void){}
CCollision::~CCollision(void){}

bool CCollision::checkLine( float *triangle, CVec &p )
{
    CVec p1 = CVec( triangle[0], triangle[1], triangle[2] );
    CVec p2 = CVec( triangle[3], triangle[4], triangle[5] );
    CVec p3 = CVec( triangle[6], triangle[7], triangle[8] );
    return checkLine( p1, p2, p3, p );

}

bool CCollision::checkLine( float *v1, float *v2, float *v3, CVec &p )
{
    CVec p1 = CVec( v1[0], v1[1], v1[2] );
    CVec p2 = CVec( v2[0], v2[1], v2[2] );
    CVec p3 = CVec( v3[0], v3[1], v3[2] );
    return checkLine( p1, p2, p3, p );
}

bool CCollision::checkLine( CVec &v1, CVec &v2, CVec &v3, CVec &p )
{
    CVec sect;

    // Find Triangle Normal, then normalize it (use Magnitude)
    CVec Normal;
    Normal = ( v2 - v1 )%( v3 - v1 );
    Normal.Normalize(); // Normalize

    // Find the distance to the plane, based on the Normal.
    float distanceNear = (vnear-v1)^Normal;
    float distanceFar  = (vfar-v1)^Normal;

    if (( (distanceNear * distanceFar) >= 0.0f)||( distanceNear == distanceFar))
        return false; // Are they equal?

    // Find exact intersection point.
    sect = vnear + (vfar-vnear) * ( -distanceNear/(distanceFar-distanceNear) );

    // Check all points against the Normalized vector.
    CVec v;

    // Point 1
    v = Normal%( v2-v1 );
    if ( (v^( sect-v1 )) < 0.0f )
        return false;

    // Point 2
    v = Normal%( v3-v2 );
    if ( (v^( sect-v2 )) < 0.0f )
        return false;

    // Point 3
    v = Normal%( v1-v3 );
    if ( (v^( sect-v1 )) < 0.0f )
        return false;

    // Lastly, lets set the intersection point.
    p = sect;

    return true;
}


void CCollision::projectRay( int x, int y )
{
    GLint viewport[4];
    GLdouble modelview[16];
    GLdouble projection[16];
    GLdouble PosX, PosY, x1, x2, x3;

    glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview );
    glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection);

    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);

    PosX = (float)x;
    PosY = (float)viewport[3] - (float)y;

    gluUnProject( PosX, PosY, 0, modelview, projection, viewport, &x1, &x2, &x3);
    vnear.x = (float)x1; vnear.y = (float)x2; vnear.z = (float)x3;
    gluUnProject( PosX, PosY, 1.0, modelview, projection, viewport, &x1, &x2, &x3);
    vfar.x = (float)x1; vfar.y = (float)x2; vfar.z = (float)x3;
}
```

The way to use the code above is to capture the input and specify the needed data:

```
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    project->scene->bCheckForCollision = true;
project->scene->collision.projectRay(
        LOWORD(((LPARAM *)m.LParam.ToPointer())),
        HIWORD((LPARAM *)m.LParam.ToPointer())
```

);
                         }
That would be using a mouse click as the capture, though we want to do it from a perspective matrix in all reality.

This code above comes from a working terrain generator I wrote back in 2005.

Alternatively, another way would be to run the inTriangle code I previously provided, then detecting slope for each side of the triangle.  This would require rolling through all points.

A better way would be to create a perspective matrix like the one we described above.  For a visual example of what you need to do:

rotate a camera to be looking directly down on the player

(c)-----> Player [ (terrain)

now, using the same concept I originally posted, you can identify the intersect point by creating a near/far vector from the perspective.  This never needs to be drawn, but you are casting a ray to the exact point.

Comment: I shall try this code first, i've got experience with cpp and opengl in cpp so all should go well. Looks like this is perfect, the only bit i dont get is the 
        LOWORD(((LPARAM *)m.LParam.ToPointer())),
        HIWORD((LPARAM *)m.LParam.ToPointer())
What does that mean?